# SQL query to select max value of a varchar field

Tags: sql, select, varchar

I want to select the max value of a varchar field and increment its value by 1 retaining its original format ..

Customer ID for ex. : `CUS0000001` is the value

add 1 to it and then enter it into the database along with other details.

So the result should be like `CUS0000002` ..

This is what I have tried and in fact achieved what I want ..

But is this the best way to do it ??

```
SELECT 
   CONCAT('CUS', RIGHT(CONCAT('000000', CONVERT((CONVERT(MAX(RIGHT(customer_id, 7)) , UNSIGNED) + 1), CHAR(10))), 7)) AS customer_id 
FROM customer_master
```

Comment: Is it always 3 letters and rest digits?

Comment: This is not safe against concurrent updates. Better use a SEQUENCE.

Comment: Would it not be more sensible just to use a number but always format the customer number output as you wish?

Comment: Can you alter the database? It makes more sense to simply use an integer for the ID and skip the "CUS" because of this very issue. If you let the database assign the ID with a sequence, you don't have to do this.

Comment: Also, for performance reasons, do the MAX before the RIGHT, so you have a chance of an index being used to find the highest value (only works if the first three letters are fixed, and then it does not make sense to store them really, as @BugFinder points out).

Comment: What database system/product?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - that doesn't really say anything about what database you're using and which features might be available to solve this problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the commenters that the database should not be designed like this.  However, if you are stuck with it, I suggest something like this to get the highest value:

```
select customer_id from customer_master 
    order by customer_id desc 
    fetch first row only;
```

Then generate the new value by performing your logic on the result that is returned.  This will be much faster, because the substring operations will be quite slow, and in this case they will only be performed once.

(This assumes that every ID will have the same prefix, namely 'CUS'; however, your code seems to imply that).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(RIGHT(CusID, 7)) AS id
FROM tblCustomer
```